# How to use sql command to update an sql table in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following SQL query which works in SQL server management :

```
Update SQLTableBlokke
set blokgemiddeld = ((tha_min4 + tha_min3 + tha_min2 + 
        tha_min1 + tha_huidig) / 
    NULLIF(((ABS(sign(tha_min4))+ABS(sign(tha_min3))+ABS(sign(tha_min2))+
        ABS(sign(tha_min1))+ABS(sign(tha_huidig))) * 1.00),0))
```

As a beginner I have trouble using this command as a vb.net command. I have tried the following :

```
        Dim konneksie As New SqlConnection
        Dim opdraggem As New SqlCommand

        konneksie.ConnectionString = "Data Source=GIDEON-E-    LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=BlokwinsgewendheidDatabasis;Integrated     Security=True"
        konneksie.Open()
        opdraggem.Connection = konneksie

    opdraggem.CommandText = "Update(SQLTableBlokke)" & _
    "blokgemiddeld = @((tha_min4 + tha_min3 + tha_min2 + tha_min1 + tha_huidig) / " & _
    " NULLIF(((ABS(sign(tha_min4)) + ABS(sign(tha_min3)) + ABS(sign(tha_min2)) + ABS(sign(tha_min1)) + ABS(sign(tha_huidig))) * 1.0), 0)) "


    opdraggem.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

However I get the error message : Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '('. The cursor stops at the  opdraggem.ExecuteNonQuery() line.

I think I have to use parameters, but have no idea how to implement them.

Any help to a newbie would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the key word "set" in your vb code, opdraggem.CommandText =

Comment: I don't think the you copied the command as is.. the SET and some spaces missing.. to avoid mistakes, just paste it in one line.. might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any need for you to use parameters in this case as you are not updating with any data not already in the table. Your CommandText should just be:

```
 opdraggem.CommandText = "Update SQLTableBlokke" & _
"set blokgemiddeld = ((tha_min4 + tha_min3 + tha_min2 + " & _
    "tha_min1 + tha_huidig) / " & _
"NULLIF(((ABS(sign(tha_min4))+ABS(sign(tha_min3))+ABS(sign(tha_min2))+ " & _
    "ABS(sign(tha_min1))+ABS(sign(tha_huidig))) * 1.00),0))"
```

Your code will also benefit from a using statement on the connection as it will ensure the connection always gets closed. Demonstrated here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Yes indeed I missed the keyword "Set".
Regards